# new Rengine(...); fails without error

Tags: java, eclipse, r, rjava, jri

I'm trying to set up JRI with Eclipse on a Windows 7 x64 system. I tried it once on my Laptop and it worked. Now on my Desktop it fails although everything of the R, rJava and JRI installation is exactly the same.

I set the JRI and R Paths correctly to: 
`C:\Program Files\R\R-2.15.1\library\rJava\jri;C:\Program Files\R\R-2.15.1\bin\x64`

Also I set `R_DOC_DIR` etc in Eclipse.

Every time I try to run `new Rengine(...);` it fails without any error or exception. Debugging revealed an: `<terminated, exit value: 10>C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\javaw.exe (01.10.2012 18:00:31)`

Is there anything I can try? It really bothers me that it works an my Laptop but not on my Workstation despite the same settings everywhere.

Edit: The code that is used to get the Rengine object.

```
public static Rengine getRengine(){
    if (re == null) createRengine();
    return re;
}

public static void createRengine(){
    if (re!=null) return;
    try{
        if (!Rengine.versionCheck()) {
            System.err.println("** Version mismatch **");
            System.exit(1);
        }  
        String[] arguments = {"--save"};
        re=new Rengine(arguments, false, null);
        if (!re.waitForR()) {
            System.out.println("Cannot load R");
            return;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Edit: The last time i tried it i got an errormessage (creating of the REngine worked, this happened never before), R was missing a registryentry. After installing R 2.15.1 again it suddenly worked. Now after a restart it's the same like before. The program crashes at the creation of the REngine.

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example...

Comment: Do you mean an example of the code i'm using?

Comment: A piece of code which will enable us to reproduce your problem.

Comment: @PaulHiemstra Ok i edited the code in.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the exact same problem. It turns out I had unchecked the box that asks to make a registry entry with the R version number. Once I let the installer run with that box checked, it seemed to work.

I would make sure your regedit looks like this:
[image: Screencap of regedit]

Next up: getting this working in a portable way...

Answer (score 0):

I am using R 3.2.2 and eclipse Mars on Windows 10 x64.

I faced the described issue today and tried around a bit. Finally, I found the root cause in the build path. Please check whether the following conditions are fulfilled:

1.) The following Java libraries from the JIRI folder on your hard disk shall be included as (user) libraries:

- JIRI.jar
- REngine.jar
- JRIEngine.jar

2.) The native library **jiri.dll** is located in the subfolder "i386" for x86, whereas for x64 it is available in the subfolder "x64". The relevant one shall be added as separate **native library location** to the Java Build Path of the eclipse project. Otherwise, the file may not be considered as it is not located in the main JIRI folder.

Best regards

Philipp